# Swift protocol is not setting the label value and is nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, protocols

I want to call the label from ViewController and set it at different points in the code for example there are 2 different functions and both of them will set the label to lets say "hi" and 2nd function will set it to "hello"

I used Swift3 protocol way just like this: [Access label.text from separate class in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705166/access-label-text-from-separate-class-in-swift)

I have another init in the class so I'm not sure why it would not set the label text to new values but is nil.

I hit the connect button first.

Here is my code:

```
protocol HiResponder: class {
    func hi()
    func hello()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, HiResponder {

@IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!
var test: Test!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

test.responder = self //gives me nil fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
}

@IBAction func connectBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        self.test = Test(
            p1: "hey",
            p2: "there"
        )
        self.test.connect(p1: "hey", p2: "there")
    }

func hi() {
        status.text = "hi"
    }
    hello() {
        status.text = "hello"
    }

}
```

This is the class that sets the value of these responders:

```
class Test {

    var test:TestQQ?
    var p1:String?
    var p2: String?

weak var responder: HiResponder?

init(p1: String, p2:String) {
  self.p1 = p1
  self.p2 = p2
}

init(responder: TestResponder) {
  self.responder = responder
}

 // Connect
 func connect(p1:String, p2:String) {
        //code
 }

func setHello(){
  responder?.hello()
}


func setHi(){
  responder?.hi()
}

}
```

I tried to generalize my code but thats the idea. My connect function is being called in my viewDidload of viewController.

Comment: Are you setting `responder` anywhere?  The code you have shown doesn't allocate a `Test` instance and has other issues. It is ok to simplify your code but you should make sure that that code is a valid [MCVE] otherwise we are solving problems in your sample, not your actual code.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am not setting responder anywhere. But how can I? and where can I?

Comment: That's how the delegation pattern works; when you create an instance of `Test` in your `ViewController` you set `test.responder=self` so now the `Test` instance has a reference back to the view controller.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have added the complete example now

Comment: @Paulw11 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when I try to do "test.responder = self"

Comment: You have declared `test` but you haven't assigned an instance of `Test` to it.

Comment: @Paulw11 if I assign an instance by basically doing `test.responder = Test(self)` and it does not assign the label text at all.

Comment: No. test doesn't implement your delegate methods. You want `test=Test()   test.responder=self` so that your view controller instance is the test classes delegate

Answer (score 0):

You didn't instantiate test. Since viewdidload will run first it is of course nil. Therefore, you cannot acces anything from it. What you need to do is find a spot to instantiate it first before you use it. Maybe in connectBTN you can set the responder after you create it instead lf in viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

The solution to deal with the unwrapped nil Optional value is to set test as an Optional Test object.

There is another problem though. You never actually use either of the functions from the protocol. hi() or hello()

Below I used both functions from the protocol but not from another class. In fact I didn't use Test at all. Not sure what your goal was with using a different class to set the Label text.

```
protocol HiResponder: class {
    func hi()
    func hello()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, HiResponder {

    @IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!
    var num = 1
    var test: Test?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        test?.responder = self //gives me nil fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    }

    @IBAction func connectBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if num % 2 == 0 {
            hi()
        } else {
            hello()
        }
        num += 1
    }

    func hi() {
        status.text = "hi"
    }

    func hello() {
        status.text = "hello"
    }
}

class Test {

    var test: Test?
    var p1: String?
    var p2: String?

    weak var responder: HiResponder?

    init(p1: String, p2:String) {
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
    }

    init(responder: HiResponder) {
        self.responder = responder
    }

    // Connect
    func connect(p1:String, p2:String) {
        //code
    }

    func setHello(){
        responder?.hello()
    }

    func setHi(){
        responder?.hi()
    }
}
```